# Import error in relation of DLL functions

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7.2.

i'm using DLL to talk with external hardware , by using the below lines:

**main.py**

```
comm_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("extcomm.dll")  
ret_val =  comm_dll.open(0)
```

the `ret_val` is needed in all other DLL functions because several hardware of the same type can be connected to the same PC
the `comm_dll` is needed in several modules that needs access to this DLL functions

My question is how I make other modules to know `comm_dll` and `ret_val` variables
I try to import them from main by `import from main comm_dll,ret_val`   or by using `global` keyword on both of the variables and then import them
No matter what I do , other modules failed on import statement

I know I can pass these variables to all the functions that uses them , but its seems big overhead

what is the pythonic way to do such import?

**Note** : ret_val type is `ctypes.c_int`

**CODE**

```
main.py

import ctypes  
from drv_spi import  *

def main():

    comm_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("extcomm.dll")

    comm_dll.open.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
    comm_dll.open.restypes = ctypes.c_int

    comm_handle =  comm_dll.open(0)

    drv_spi_init()  
main()

drv_spi.py

import ctypes

def drv_spi_init():

    comm_dll.spi_config.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    comm_dll.spi_config.restypes = ctypes.c_int

    ret_val = comm_dll.spi_config(comm_handle,0x45)
```

I get an error of `NameError: global name 'comm_dll' is not defined`

using `from main  import comm_dll` is not working either because main to run again...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should probably implement your hardware device as a class. Something like

```
class MyHardwareDevice(object):
    comm_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("extcomm.dll")

    def __init__(self):
        pass      # or whatever initialization you need

    def connect(self, port_number):
        self.ret_val = comm_dll.open(port_number)
```

Then you can use the class like

```
device = MyHardwareDevice()
device.connect(0)
# your ret_val is now available as device.ret_val
```

Comment: I need to connect to hardware only once , in one module , and then use the `ret_val` in several modules , each of them using other functions from the DLL (module for SPI functions , module for I2C functions...)

Comment: It’s still not a bad idea to encapsulate your device in a class like this. Anyway, can you show us the module you’ve already written, along with the errors you get when you try to use it?